# Gmail: What is a jQuery selector for incoming mail senders only? How to work with highly compressed and nested CSS in general?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, html-parsing

As the title says, how do you work with parsing highly compressed and nested structures such as a Gmail page?

I'm writing a script for internal use (customer service) to extract incoming email addresses for the open thread and pull relevant orders based on the email address.

#### Here's what I've found so far

`$("#canvas_frame").contents().find("...`

- `span.gD` is a list of all **visible** senders in the current thread. Excludes hidden messages within the thread when emails start to stack to conserve space.
- `span.yP` is a list of all senders, visible or not (including ones in your inbox it seems)

I'm trying to find which class gmail is using to style incoming vs outgoing mail - how would you go about tackling this? I'm also trying to find a selector for all emails in the current thread.

Are there any useful tools for traversing up the DOM tree from an element and comparing common parents? Do you have any processes to recommend or tips for me?

I will probably iterate over the elements and exclude certain email addresses for `span.gD`, as it's thread specific and even a fully collapsed thread has the first email and last two emails which should be useful 99% (or some large percentage) of the time.

Still, I felt very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you not already uses [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) i would suggest it. You can ofcourse also use Safari's own developer tool or which browser you like. My point is that it might be the easiest solution.

I found that in an gmail-thread you cannot see the differences by incoming or outgoing emails directly. But you can traverse down and check the email attribute whether it is yours or another. Example:

```
if ($('span.gD').attr('email') == 'youremail')
  $(this).parent(); // Here you can go up again, and now you know this is you're outgoing email.
```

I can see that gmail uses `color` aswell, you can also check upon this, but i guess it is not as correct, if they switches colors etc.

You should be aware that Gmail have alot of frontend code. It can be very tough to traverse. And it does not use page-reloads, which means the content can seems messy with hidden HTML.